# returning Cypress.Promise from a Cypress command breaks types

Tags: typescript, cypress

The following Cypress command compiles in Cypress 8.x.x

```js
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
      login(): Chainable<Token>;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // rest
  });
});
```

But after upgrading to Cypress 9.x.x I get the following TypeScript error:

```
argument of type '() => Bluebird<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(person?: Partial<Person>) => Chainable<Token>'.
  Type 'Bluebird<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'Chainable<Token>': and, as, blur, check, and 83 more.ts(2345)
```

Comment: May I ask, what is the type of `Token`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the implementation does not match the typing: the value that's actually returned (`new Cypress.Promise(…)`) is a promise, or more strictly `PromiseLike`, but not a `Token`<sup>1</sup>.

Since Cypress uses Bluebird promises, in order to match the implementation, the return type of `login()` must also be a bluebird promise; you can import the symbol from Cypress package like that:

```
import type Bluebird from "cypress/types/bluebird";

declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            login(): Bluebird<Token>;
        }
    }
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/NBe9Vw)<sup>2</sup>.*

<sup>1 – FWIW, the OP does not disclose what `Token` is, so technically it can be `PromiseLike`, in which case my answer is useless, – but IMO this is unlikely. In any case, the corresponding question by user @PeaceAndQuiet was ignored, so I have to make the assumption that `Token` is not a `PromiseLike` (probably an access token).</sup>

<sup>2 – Note that `cypress` might not get "picked up" by the playground, for some reason; it is npm-installed though (go to Plugins → scroll down)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There were some breaking changes in 9.0.0.
See [changelog for 9.0.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#9-0-0)
The one that might be impacting you is the 6th one from the top.
It is the one that addresses feature [17496](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/17496).

You should replace `<Token>` by something that will accept bluebird promises. Or just set it to `<any>`.

```js
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
      login(): Chainable<any>;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript error was due to a breaking change in version 9.0.0. See  [changelog](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#9-0-0):

> Custom command implementations are now typed based on the declared custom chainables. Addresses [#17496](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/17496).

This means that now your return value in the implementation must match the declared typings/custom chainables.

In your case, in the implementation you are returning a [Bluebird promise](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise):

```
return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... });
```

You should now update your typing interface to match type, which could either be:

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      login(): Cypress.Promise<Token>;
    }
  }
}
```

Or, as per @Dima Parzhitsky's suggestion:

```
import type Bluebird from 'cypress/types/bluebird';

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      login(): Bluebird<Token>;
    }
  }
}
```